# Voice Chat Options

Tags: xmpp, chat, voice, openfire

I am trying to implement a Voice chat on my website. I am currently using XMPP / Openfire for IM Chat and would like to incorporate a "Chatroom" option where up to (25 to 50 or more if possible) people can join and voice chat with each other. I was looking at Openfire's RedFire option but it has a maximum of 12 users per room. Video is not needed.

Does anyone know of any openfire plugins and/or other solutions that will meet my requirements? Open to any options.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Got a response from a member on the Openfire forum see here for more information: http://community.igniterealtime.org/message/224079#224079